# Use pgcrypto module on EclipseLink

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, eclipselink

I have read from this [link](https://thorben-janssen.com/map-encrypted-database-columns-hibernates-columntransformer-annotation/) that you can use `pgcrypto` in `Hibernate` using `@ColumnTransformer`. Does `EclipseLink` have similar function? Based on my research I can only use `@Transformation` which only transform the data in Application level.